# Folding of comments in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, folding, code-regions

For a long time I was looking for a way to fold comments in PyCharm. Basically I was looking for a way to achieve the same `+` for comments as for the block of code.

[image: screenshot of code in editor]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easy to achieve this with

```
#region Description 
# all your comments go here
#endregion
```

or this:

```
// <editor-fold desc="Description"> 
// all your comments go here
// </editor-fold>
```

Important thing to remember is that you can not mix both kinds of folding.

Also instead of typing all these `#region Desription` you can just press `CRTL+ALT+T` (but not on ubuntu, where this combination is for opening terminal) or going to `Code -> Surround With` and selecting your surrounding type.

Using this type of surrounding you can fold any arbitrary parts of the code. But you can also do this with `CTRL + .`

Answer (score 2):

Comment folding has been available for a while now. Any multi-line comment, regardless of type (`#`, `"""`), will cause clickable folding icons to show up.

[image]

The `#region` feature is still useful, if you want to fold mixed content.